# sort and group dict of list if list contains others

Tags: python, group-by

I have a dict of lists
`dict = {k1:[v1],k2:[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5],k3:[v2,v3],k4[v1,v2]}`
i want to sort dict as the next elements have previous elements e.g.

```
OrderedDict = ((k1,[v1]),(k4,[v1,v2]),(k3,[v2,v3]),(k2,[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]))
```

and sorted based on their priority:

```
SortedGroup = [1:((k1,[v1])),2:((k4,[v1,v2]),(k3,[v2,v3])),3:(k2,[v1,v2,v3,v4,v5]))]
```

i have tried `sorted(dict.items(),key = lambda x: len(x[1]))` but it's based on `len(list)` only not list elements. Thought about permutation but have not seen many examples with them.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: You can try something like this.

    print (sorted(ord1.items(),key = lambda x: ( len(x[1]),''.join(x[1] ))))

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official documentation first, there is actually an example for that [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

> > > OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)))

Comment: it doesn't work as next one must contains previous not only has more elements

Comment: oh sorry I didn't catch the must contain previous elements part. can you be more specific about this? what if there are 2 elements which children is unique and are not contained within other elements, etc?